# Looking for a book about a man who loses his memory, and travels between worlds

Tags: story-identification, books

At the beginning of the story, the man has no memory. Step by step he starts to recollect some details. He travels into a world and discovers that he created it. There is an antagonist (male), who tried to kill him and wiped his memory in the process, hence the memory loss.

I would be happy if anyone knows this book and can help with the name and author.

Edit:
I know that  Amber series by Zelazny answers this description, but it is not the book I am looking for.

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: Roughly more than 10 years ago. I wish I could add information on the cover, though I don't remember.

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to propose this as an answer, but you might be looking for the "World of Tiers" series by Philip José Farmer.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin thanks, but this is not the book I am looking for.

Comment: It has some resemblance to "The Book of Ptath" by Van Vogt.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez, thanks. The antagonist is supposed to be a male character. I have edited the question.

Comment: Also vague enough to be the first Amber series by Zelazny.

Comment: @OrganicMarble, thanks. I know this follows the description exactly. I am familiar with this book and it is similar but not the one. I am editing the question to exclude this.

Comment: I considered "Crisis!" by James E Gunn, which has some similarities, but I don't think there is an actual individual antagonist.